# How can I make this work, array Image?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Image[] facultati ={R.drawable.faculate_1, R.drawable.faculatate_2, R.drawable.facultate_3, R.drawable.facultate_4};
        ArrayAdapter<Image> faculati_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Image>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,facultati);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_facultati);
        myList.setAdapter(faculati_adapter);
    }
}
```

I want to make a list of Images but i cannot make it work, i don't know how to make the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources from your R folder are of type integer.
You should declare your array of type Integer
And you should probably use a custom adapter to display Images, or a cardView

Comment: It's showing numbers because you've used `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. 
You can use a `ImageView[]` array of fixed size and add imageResource to them, then use that array in your adapter initialization, however it will String instead of the actual image.
Use a custom Adapter, with a layout that has a imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
  Integer[] facultati ={R.drawable.faculate_1, R.drawable.faculatate_2, R.drawable.facultate_3, R.drawable.facultate_4};

ArrayAdapter <Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,facultati );
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom adapter for this like below code

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>{
 public class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView image;
}

public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> users) {
   super(context, R.layout.item_user, users);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Integer user = getItem(position);    
   ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
   if (convertView == null) {
      viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
      convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
   } else {
       viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
   viewHolder.image.setDrawable(user);
  return convertView;
```

}
}